# Numpy savez exceptions

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, io, save

I recently found this statement:

> np.savez is not multi-process safe, because it always uses
>   gettempdir() +  key + ".npy". So, if you're running the same script
>   over different data  sets, you will roach your own data when one
>   process removes the  /tmp/arr_0.npy of another process.
>
> As luck would have it, I'm in that exact situation, so I have an
>   example  error:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
> "/home/pedro/prospectus/prelim/bbvs/bin/skldthresh", line 99, in <module> main()    
> File "/home/pedro/prospectus/prelim/bbvs/bin/skldthresh", line 90, in  main
>  np.savez("%smask-t%0.2f" % (outfile,threshold), result)    
> File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/io.py", line 230, in savez
>  zip.write(filename, arcname=fname)    
>  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/zipfile.py", line 541, in write
>   st = os.stat(filename)  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/arr_0.npy'
> ```
>
> Fortunately, replacing `tempfile.gettempdir()` with `tempfile.mkdtemp()`
>   AND  remembering to clean up at the end with `os.rmdir(direc)` is all it
>   takes to  fix it as far as I can tell.

What does this exactly mean and how can I personally avoid this? Does numpy store the data written to an `.npz` file in temporary files, which are potentially named like other temporary `.npz` files in other scripts?!

I have some scientific experiments which run over several hours and save their results via `np.savez`. The destination path for the results saved with `savez` is different, so every experiment has its own result path. However, they the scripts themselves are located in the same directory.

Interestingly the scripts sometimes run several hours before this error occurs:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/work/var/slurmd/state.node348.d/job20832/slurm_script", line 53, in
> <module>
>     E = Exp6_06()   File
> "/work/experiments/s06/cs06_ex06.py", line
> 150, in __init__
>     self.__start()   File "/work/experiments/s06/cs06_ex06.py", line
> 374, in __start
>     File "/home/fx092/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
> line 600, in savez_compressed
>     _savez(file, args, kwds, True)   File "/home/fx092/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
> line 630, in _savez
>     fd, tmpfile = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='-numpy.npy')   File "/sw/env/openmpi/2Q4/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py",
> line 314, in mkstemp
>     return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)   File "/sw/env/openmpi/2Q4/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py",
> line 244, in _mkstemp_inner
>     fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600) OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/work/tmp/node001.admin.2016-03-06-152506.fx092.27432/tmp5UulEz-numpy.npy'
```

**Used numpy version**: 1.10.4

Comment: A `npz` file is a `zip` archive.  `savez` saves each variable in a different file, and then collects them into the archive.

Comment: Yes..and if multiple processes work at the same time this means possibly different scripts act on the same temporary files?!

Comment: Note that the quote you have is out of date --- savez is in general safe to use in parallel. The error that you get is most likely because something removed the directory `/work/tmp/node001.admin.2016-03-06-152506.fx092.27432` --- this directory comes from your runtime environment (usually the `TMPDIR`/`TEMP` environment variable). Things to look for --- does your own script remove this directory, or maybe the node runtime environment cleans it up before all jobs have finished, or maybe there is some mpi configuration issue in which job-specific dirs are created but only one of them is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs in `mkstemp`.  The quote suggests using `mkdtemp` instead:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

> tempfile.mkstemp([suffix=''[, prefix='tmp'[, dir=None[, text=False]]]])
>
> Creates a temporary file in the most secure manner possible. There are no race conditions in the file’s creation, assuming that the platform properly implements the os.O_EXCL flag for os.open(). The file is readable and writable only by the creating user ID. If the platform uses permission bits to indicate whether a file is executable, the file is executable by no one. The file descriptor is not inherited by child processes.

and

> tempfile.mkdtemp([suffix=''[, prefix='tmp'[, dir=None]]])
>
> Creates a temporary directory in the most secure manner possible. There are no race conditions in the directory’s creation. The directory is readable, writable, and searchable only by the creating user ID.
>
> The user of mkdtemp() is responsible for deleting the temporary directory and its contents when done with it.

The quoted error appears to occur after the temp files have been created, and they are being collected into the `zip`.  Your error appears to occur while Creating one of the temp files.

I haven't used these functions enough to understand the difference.
 We may need to study `_savez` in `lib/npyio.py`.

What OS are you using?  Linux, mac, windows?

---

Here's the core of `_savez`, now in the `lib/npyio.py` file:

```
def _savez(file, args, kwds, compress):
    ....
    zip = zipfile_factory(file, mode="w", compression=compression)

    # Stage arrays in a temporary file on disk, before writing to zip.
=>  fd, tmpfile = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='-numpy.npy')
    os.close(fd)
    try:
        for key, val in namedict.items():
            fname = key + '.npy'
            fid = open(tmpfile, 'wb')
            try:
                format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
                fid.close()
                fid = None
=>              zip.write(tmpfile, arcname=fname)
            finally:
                if fid:
                    fid.close()
    finally:
        os.remove(tmpfile)
    zip.close()
```

The quoted error occurs toward the end of the loop, when the temp 'save' file is added to the archive.  Your error occurs early, when it is getting the temp dir and temp file (fd).  Note that discards the open file handle, and just uses the name (repeatedly for each array).

It's surprising that the temp directory should have disappeared during the `mkstemp` function call.  It almost feels like an `openmpi` problem rather than a `savez` one.

Comment: I am using Linux only.

Comment: OK, so file permissions shouldn't be an issue.